# React Navigation: Navigating outside a component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate my app from outside of a component. Specifically, I am using a fetch interceptor and I want to navigate whenever an error response is received.

I followed the example here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

However, my app is still giving me an error saying that either a navigator isn't rendered or the navigator hasn't finished mounting:

[Screenshot of app with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZZuv.jpg)

As far as I can tell, neither of those situations apply. The app is loaded and rendered with a navigator in place before I try to actually navigate

My App.jsx:

```
// ... imports and so on ...

fetchIntercept.register({
  response: (response) => {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      // Unverified subscription
      RootNavigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: 'Intercept' }] });
    }
    return response;
  },
});

{ ... }

const InterceptNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Application: {
      screen: ApplicationScreen,
    },
    Intercept: {
      screen: SubscriptionInterceptScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteKey: 'Application',
  },
);

const App = createAppContainer(InterceptNavigator);

export default () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    RootNavigation.isMountedRef.current = true;
    return () => { RootNavigation.isMountedRef.current = false; };
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={RootNavigation.navigationRef}>
      <App />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

RootNavigation.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const isMountedRef = React.createRef();

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (isMountedRef.current && navigationRef.current) {
    navigationRef.current.navigate(name, params);
  }
}

export function reset(options) {
  if (isMountedRef.current && navigationRef.current) {
    navigationRef.current.reset(options);
  }
}
```

I also inserted a number of console logs throughout and all of them showed that the app is loaded, that the navigationRef is current, and that the isMountedRef is also current *before* the app tries to navigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The issue is that I had a mixture of version 4 and version 5 code (and was referring to mixed documentation).

To fix the issue I removed references to version 5 code and then followed the steps on this page to get the navigator working: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Answer (score 0):

Try `.resetRoot()` instead of `.reset()`. I think `.reset()` needs a state as an argument.